# Creating a UIButton that pages back to the previous page

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm sure this is super simple but I'm new to iOS development so I must be missing something.

In xcode I have a like 5 page app and I can navigate forward no problem... To navigate backwards shouldn't I be able to create the button, then simply control and drag to the page I want it to go back to?

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you using multiple view controllers in Storyboard? Or are you using a UIPageViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is called an unwind segue. If using swift, this is how to do it.

Write this code in the view controller file that you want to go back to:

```
@IBAction func unwindToPreviousScreen(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

After writing this code, go to the storyboard, and go to view controller that is the one you don't want to go back to, and `control-drag` from the view controller to the exit icon in the tab bar of the view controller (far right icon). Make sure you have clicked on the view controller.

It doesn't have to be `unwindToPreviousScreen`, it can be whatever you like, but be sure to keep the `unwindTo` part intact.

Apologies if you are using a different language, I am just a swift person.